# Untitled dynamic playlist with YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am dynamically making a playlist on my page using the YouTube Player API Reference for iframe. I cannot figure out how to change the title of the playlist. It always stays "Untitled playlist". Please help!

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('youtube-player', {
        width: '100%',
        loadPlaylist:{
            listType:'playlist',
            list: youtubeIdsArr,
            index:parseInt(0),
            suggestedQuality:'small'
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }


    });
  }
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
      event.target.cuePlaylist(youtubeIdsArr);

  }
  var done = false;

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
```

Comment: Please add your current code.

Comment: No way, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

try adding this,

```
title="Playlist: Kitchen Pilates Playlist"
```

Comment: Is this something that has worked for you or is this just a guess on your part?...I'm not trying to be sarcastic it's an honest question. And can you be more specific about where you are suggesting that line be added in the code? I'm asking because I have the same question as the author. Thanks.